# How to replace a string in Android?

Tags: java, string

I have a string for example "my sample string@android".I want to the string before the @ symbol
That means i don't want the string after @ symbol

Please any one help me with some source code

Comment: Please post the code snippet that is giving you the problem

Comment: You replace strings in Android the same way you replace strings in Java. If you don't know how to do that, refer to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Do you mean String s = "sample string @ 123e3"? Is this string coming from a resource file? Please update your question with such details, and provide at least the whole method that is causing this problem. Or people here at SO will downvote your question :)

Comment: String a="Sample android text @123de"; I want a new string like String b="Sample android text"

Comment: Ok then refer to what @hovanessyan posted you. This is a simple java related question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the string and take the first part:

```
String string = "sample string @whatever@test";
String[] splitted = string.split("@");
```

Then `splitted[0] = "sample string "`, `splitted[1] = "whatever"` and `splitted[2] = "test"`.

So if you always want the part *before* the `"@"` you can write

```
String string = "sample string @whatever@test";
String firstPart = string.split("@")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks stefan satisfied my requirement

Answer (score -2):

Use the `indexOf` and `substring` methods of String according to your requirements.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html shows how these methods function and gives you other options as well...